# Elasticsearch: search using a doc's property value as part of the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data set where each document has a 'Name' property that may be used in another property, 'Text', e.g.

```js
{
  name: "Bob",
  text: "Put a fish on Bob. This fish grants Bob the power of Fish-Slapping Dance."
},
{
  name: "Cam"
  text: "Put a hammer on Cam. This hammer grants Cam the power of Hammertime."
}
```

Right now, I'd have to do a search something like 'grants the power of', which would turn up these as likely matches, for sure, but I'd like to be able to do 'grants ~ the power of', where ~ is defined as a specific property of that document, in this case 'Name'. So, when it searches the first doc it would search for 'grants Bob the power of', and the second, 'grants Cam the power of'.

I don't need that property to be dynamic, since in my use case it'll never change, but I haven't found anything that lets me use a document's property value in a search query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding more fields to your model.  something like:

```
{
  name: "Cam"
  text: "Put a hammer on Cam. This hammer grants Cam the power of Hammertime.",
  who: "cam"
  action: "grant",
  thing: "power"
  what: "hammertime"
}
```

You could then query something like this:

```
GET devdev/audittrail/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "who": "cam"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "action": "grant"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "thing": "power"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "what": "hammertime"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, my real dataset is much larger (about 16,000 items) and the scenarios in which the name could be used are much, much wider/varied, so it'd be an impossible/interminable job to try to break that down into terms. Isn't there a simple way to substitute ~ with the name value?